# While porting from Jackson 2.5.0 to 2.9.5 or 2.7.0, json enum response not coming as expected

Tags: java, json, enums, jackson

I am having a Java Response Class, it's response is given to JSON over the web.  Till  Jackson 2.5.0 all Enums are coming with it's string value, but in 2.9.5 (2.7.0 onwards) json response is taking Enum Name which ever case is given.
IN Jackson 2.5.0 Response: CInfo enum => userid is coming in lowercase it's string value, but from 2.7.0 it's coming in UPPERCASE(as the name of Enum Field, not it's string value). How to resolve this issue by not changing the java CInfo.java.

Java Response Class is containing Enum.

```
public class LogResponse  {

private CInfo idInfo;

public CInfo getInfo() {
return idInfo;
}

}
===============
public class CInfo {
public static Enum KeyFields {
  USERID("userid");
        private String value;

        KeyFields(final String aStringValue) {
            value= aStringValue;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return value;
        }
}
}
```

2.5.0 Json Response contains "userid"
But 2.7.0 Json Response contains "USERID"

Comment: try adding `@JsonProperty("userid")` just above the line `USERID("userid");`

Comment: ah, sorry, just saw that you want a solution that doesn't require changing `CInfo.java`

Comment: are you sure you have not modified something else too while upgrading? like setting a property `SerializeFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING` or unsetting it?